# how to add extjs panel in the particular position according to html code

Tags: extjs

I would like to create an EXT panel and added into particular position. The place is `<div class= "group-list"></div>`.
Here is part of html code:

```
<header>
            <h1><span>Project 2</span>Chat Group List</h1>
        </header>
        <div class= "group-list"></div>
        <div class= "form">
            <form id= "toolform" onsubmit= "">
                <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="group name or email" type="text">
                <input class="buttom" id="submit" name="submit" value="CreateGroup" type="button" onclick="creategroup();">
                <input class="buttom" id="submit" name="submit" value="DeleteGroup" type="button" onclick="deletegroup();">
                <input class="buttom" id="submit" name="submit" value="InviteMember" type="button" onclick="invite();">
            </form>
        </div>
```

My question is: is it possbile for ext js to create a panel and place the panel to the pointed position according to html code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

See the [`renderTo`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-renderTo) config option.

```
new Ext.panel.Panel({
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    title: 'Foo',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody().down('.group-list') // Grab the first element that matches .group-list
});
```